# Store values parsed through PHP SImple HTML DOM into mysql database

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am trying to store an array of values parsed through PHP SImple HTML DOM into a mysql database

I am using the following code

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","passphrase");
if (!$con)
{
die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

function scrapper() {

$html = file_get_html('http://www.websiteiwishtoparse.whatever');
foreach($html->find('div.listing-content') as $business) {

$item['name'] = trim($business->find('div.business-name a.url', 0)->plaintext);

$item['street'] = trim($business->find('span.address', 0)->plaintext);

$item['state'] = trim($business->find('span.state', 0)->plaintext);

$item['phone'] = trim($business->find('span.phone', 0)->plaintext);

$ret[] = $item;


}

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);

return $ret;
}

$ret = scrapper();

$pdo = new PDO($con); 

foreach($ret as $v) {
echo $v['name'].'<br>';
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>'.$v['street'].'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$v['state'].'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$v['phone'].'</li>';
echo '</ul>';
$q = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO dbname.dbtable (name, street, state, phone) VALUES (:name, :street, :state, :phone)');
$q->execute(array('name' => $name, 'street' => $value, 'state' => $state, 'phone' =>   $phone));

}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The results are shown just fine but i am unable to store it into my db.

The error that i am getting is: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in .../scrapper.php on line 65.
I am not even sure if i am using correctly the PDO.
Even a traditional mysql_query solution would do the job.
If anybody can help me i would be grateful.
Thanx in advance

Comment: did you try and check if you are connecting to the database correctly? something like:
if($pdo){
echo 'connected';
}

Comment: Yes the connection with the database is established

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a couple of things wrong:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb', 'login', 'password');
```

Is the way to make a db-connection for mysql with PDO.

`$name`, `$street`, `$state` and `$phone` are not defined in this context. You need to use `$v['name']`, `$v['street']`, `$v['state']`, `$v['phone']`.
Instead of this:

```
$q->execute(array('name' => $name, 'street' => $value, 'state' => $state, 'phone' =>   $phone));
```

It would be better if you bindparam to assign your array variables to the query: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Can you please give me an example of code of how to store the values..You are absolutely right this is an array of values so i should use $v['name'] etc but i am a little bit confused on how to do that. Even without PDO but with mysql_query...TY

Comment: Thank you for your advice i was able to do it with the tradition mysql_query method...$sql = "INSERT INTO db.dbname (names) VALUES ('{$v['name']}')";